# Performing vector projection using ArcObjects and VB?

Tags: arcobjects, geoprocessing

I am creating a ArcGIS console application using ArcGIS 10.2 and Visual Studio 2010. I need to project a shapefile to a new location (.gdb) using console inputs and the Project tool within the Data Management toolbox. Code below:

```vb
Imports ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem
Imports ESRI.ArcGIS.Geoprocessing
Imports ESRI.ArcGIS.DataManagementTools
Module Module1
Private m_AOLicenseInitializer As LicenseInitializer = New preInGen.LicenseInitializer()

<STAThread()> _
Sub Main()
    'load product code and version to version manager
    ESRI.ArcGIS.RuntimeManager.Bind(ESRI.ArcGIS.ProductCode.Desktop)

    'ESRI License Initializer generated code.
    m_AOLicenseInitializer.InitializeApplication(New esriLicenseProductCode() {esriLicenseProductCode.esriLicenseProductCodeAdvanced}, _
    New esriLicenseExtensionCode() {})

    'get state abbreviation from user
    Console.WriteLine("State abbreviation: ")
    Console.Write(">")
    Dim StAbb As String = Console.ReadLine()

    'get FIPS from user
    Console.WriteLine("FIPS: ")
    Console.Write(">")
    Dim FIPS As String = Console.ReadLine()

    'create new geoprocesor
    Dim gp As IGeoProcessor = New GeoProcessor
    gp.OverwriteOutput = True

    'create parameter inputs
    Dim param As IVariantArray = New VarArray
    param.Add("\\\\prhqgis01\\f\\arcgisserver\\MapMS2_Data\\Parcel_Boundaries\\" & StAbb & "\\p" & FIPS & ".shp")
    param.Add("GCD_WGC_1984")
    param.Add("\\\\dvhqgis02\\d\\David\\natdb\\" & FIPS & "\\" & FIPS & "_1.gdb\\p" & FIPS & ".shp")
    param.Add("GCS_North_American_1983")
    param.Add("WGS_1984_(ITRF00)_To_NAD_1983")

    'project parcel file
    gp.Execute("Project_management", param, Nothing)

    'ESRI License Initializer generated code.
    'Do not make any call to ArcObjects after ShutDownApplication()
    m_AOLicenseInitializer.ShutdownApplication()
End Sub

End Module
```

When I do a test run, I get a generic COM exception: "Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component."

Can anyone help me find the exact source of the error?

Answer (score 2):

The order of parameters is incorrect. Have a look at the [Project tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000007m000000) help page, your parameter order must be the same as this.

Also what is "GCD_WGC_1984"? To my knowledge that's not a coordinate system, I'm guessing you meant GCS_WGS_1984? But that's academic as your parameters are out of order!